# How to loop through subdirectories and pipe input to an output file

Tags: java, linux, bash

I never made a bash before and I am struggling with creating an automated script to loop through each subdirectory to pipe an input. 
Currently I am trying to run a program in Java that is scripted to enter each user input from an input textfile and output the results.
Example of input file:

```
login
logout
```

Example of output:

```
You have logged in
You have logged out
```

The script is in the folder `/test/`

The inputs are in the subdirectories
`/test/input/somesubdirectory/someinput.txt`
What I want to do is loop through each input text to run the java and output into a folder like so

```
/test/output/somesubdirectory/output.log
```

The java is directly outside of the test folder

What I have done:

```
java Test < /test/input/login/input.txt > /test/output/login/output.txt
```

I only know how to directly access one input and one output but I am unsure on how to loop each input from each subdirectory

I have tried to do:

```
counter=0
for i in /test/input/*/*.txt;
do 
java Test < $i.txt > /test/output/login/$(counter).log
counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Comment: Some tools you may find helpful: echo your command line instead executing it; use `dirname` and `basename`; use `find`. Please consult the man pages for these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do 
   java Test < "$file" > /test/output/login/output-$((++counter)).log
done < <(find /test/input -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

[Read more about this pattern in BASH FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Does /*/*.txt not work when browsing through the files? I am receiving the error: No such file or directory

Comment: Hi, I think it's working but could you please explain what this code does?

Comment: Details of this pattern available on [BASH-FAQ-001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)